# How to get Google Drive REST api alternateLink in java?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

```
File file = mService.files().create(fileMetadata, content)
                    .setFields("id, webContentLink ,webViewLink, alternateLink").execute();

 Log.d(TAG, "File ID: " + file.getId());
 Log.d(TAG, "File web content link: " + file.getWebContentLink());     
 Log.d(TAG, "File web view link: " + file.getWebViewLink());
 Log.d(TAG, "File alternate link: " + file.????????);
```

I make a file and then want to get alternateLink but there is not such a method to get it? Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: which version are you using?

There is a `getAlternateLink()` method on `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File` for me in `v2-rev230-1.22.0`.

Comment: I am using v3-rev34-1.22.0

Answer (score 0):

[The Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) allows you to download files that are stored in Google Drive. Also, you can download exported versions of Google Documents (Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc.) in formats that your app can handle. [Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#methods) also supports providing users direct access to a file via the URL in the webViewLink property.

The metadata for a file:

```
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": string,
"etag": etag,
"selfLink": string,
"webContentLink": string,
"webViewLink": string,
"alternateLink": string,
"embedLink": string,
"openWithLinks": {
(key): string
}
```